# Python string Concatenation complexity

Tags: string, python-2.7, time-complexity

For the following code

```
str = 'abc'
str += 'd'
```

When the string is this small, I believe it's safe to say both time and space complexity is O(1).
But what if the string grows super long?
Should the time and space complexity be O(N) where N is the size of the string?

Thanks!

Comment: @theWanderer4865  Since string is immutable in python, so each concatenate should create a new string.

Comment: It's been 20 years since I took that class, but really isn't the point to say whether something is linear, squared, etc?  If you are performing a single operation, that is O(1).  If that operation is in a loop, it's O(n). The point is really to identify what scale your work is, right?

Comment: @woot  I agree with you to some degree. If the underlaying way Python implementing string concatenation is by using a loop to traverse through each char in both strings, when either of the strings is with a very large length N, I wonder if I call call that one operation O(N).